# React Material UI: Textfield maxLength not working in Android

Tags: android, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React Material UI and want to implement max length for a [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) component.

I tried to set max length in inputProps as below -

```
<TextField
    id="name"
    label="Name"
    inputProps={{ maxLength: 5 }}
 />
```

This works in desktop browsers as expected, but doesn't seem to work in mobile devices browsers, expecially in most Android mobiles with Chrome latest version.
Not sure about IOS, as not tested in that environment.

Please refer the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-materialui-textfield?file=index.js) for reference.
To replicate, please open the above stackblitz in a mobile device browser prefebaly in Chrome.

I can go with regex, but I think setting up max length attribute to a field seems very clean and semantic.

Please let know if there is any way.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution? I'm experiencing the same problem with Android. It seems to work sometimes, but after I click away from the TextField and type in again, it doesn't apply the maxLength anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If your input filed type='number' then it will not work.

You can try this solution. I think it will work.

```
<TextField
    onInput = {(e) =>{
        e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
    }}/>
```